# MVVM Passing data between two views / view models

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvvm

I have two Pages:

1. Page 1
2. Page 2

and two ViewModels with the same properties:

1. **ViewModel1** 
   Properties:

   - FirstName1
   - LastName1
2. **ViewModel2**
   Properties:

   - FirstName2
   - LastName2

Now I want to pass data(properties) between ViewModel1 to ViewModel2, and retrive this data on the Page 2.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are we talking ASP.NET MVC (4)? What have you tried so far? Can you elaborate on how the two models correlate? Can you share some code? Don't forget to clean up the question's markup as well.

Comment: I mean I would say either do it manually or create a model-class with both properties and add it to both ViewModels so you can just set one to the other.

Comment: Without knowing more, I'd suggest you take a look at Html.RenderAction, and have Page1 call render action, which has an action which returns page 2.  This only applies if you are nesting page2 in page1, if you instead want to do a redirect then that should be handled by page1's action instead of the view.

Comment: This needs to be clarified "I want to pass data(properties) between ViewModel1 to ViewModel2, and retrive this data on the Page 2."

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [MVVMLight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)'s Messenger. [Here](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/01/06/windows-phone-from-scratch%E2%80%93mvvm-light-toolkit-soup-to-nuts-3/)'s is a tutorial that could guide you on your way. Basically, the idea is to use a messenger that's independent from your Views/ViewModels to send messages from/to them. Your Views/ViewModels register and send specific messages that contain properties values you want to pass along.

Comment: The example show how pass data from View to ViewModel. He want to exchange data between two ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

You can either go with a parent ViewModel that both viewmodels inherit from or an Event Aggregator.  [Here](http://joseoncode.com/2010/04/29/event-aggregator-with-reactive-extensions/) is a simple one using Reactive Extensions.

Comment: I want achieve something like session["property"] or cookie["property"] in standard ASP.NET. So I would like pass value of property from one xaml page to another. Do you know maybe any sample MVVM application that include solution of my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your page could be constructed like so:

```
public class Page2 {

  public ViewModel1 VM1;

  public Page2() {
    VM1 = new ViewModel1(new ViewModel2());
  }
}
```

Your `ViewModel1` could look like so, with pass-through properties:

```
public class ViewModel1 : Person {

  private ViewModel2 _vm2;

  public ViewModel1(ViewModel2 vm2) {
    _vm2 = vm2;
  }

  public override string FirstName {
    get { return _vm2.FirstName; }
  }

  public override string LastName {
    get { return _vm2.LastName; }
  }
}
```

We assume your `ViewModel2` has some business logic or something

```
public class ViewModel2 : Person {
  //Etc
}
```

Both inherit from the same base class:

```
public abstract class Person {
  public abstract string FirstName { get; }
  public abstract string LastName { get; }
}
```