# MVVM wpf pass parameters between view models

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm building an application which has the following design:
A MainWindowView with 3 "child" views

- ProjectView
- ContentView
- PropertiesView3

Below is a link to a image which explains the view.

[MainWindowView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7Qaf.png)

These views are seperate Usercontrols and each has its own ViewModel. The views are declared in XAML.

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"  Margin="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="600*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="300*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="3"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="3"/>

    <Menu x:Name="MainMenu" IsMainMenu="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
        <MenuItem Header="_File" >
            <MenuItem Header="_New..." />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="_Open..." />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="_Save" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Save As..." />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="_Exit"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Edit">
            <MenuItem Header="_Cut" Command="Cut">
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Copy" Command="Copy">
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Paste" Command="Paste">
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Canvas" />
        <MenuItem Header="_View" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Window" />
        <MenuItem Header="_Help" />
    </Menu>

    <View:ProjectView x:Name="projectView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="-1,0,2,0"/>

    <View:ContentView x:Name="contentView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>

    <View:PropertiesView x:Name="propertiesView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="2,0,-1,0"/>

    <StatusBar x:Name="statusBar" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2">
        <Label x:Name="labelStatus" Content="status" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="auto"/>
    </StatusBar>

</Grid>
```

How do I send parameter between viewModels? For example: I have a listbox in the ProjectView and when I select an item I want to change the properties of the selected item in the PropertiesView. Or in the menu of the MainWindowView I want to create a new item and add this one to the list in the projectView.

Edit:
I've already searched for answers, but could not find a fitting solution for my problem.

Comment: use eventaggregator to communicate between viewmodels. Pass the parameters in events and retreive them in event listeners: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/

Comment: If you share the same ViewModel between views, there is no need to do anything special. I sometimes use a VM that fits more than one view to simplify things.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVVM Passing data between two views / view models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283199/mvvm-passing-data-between-two-views-view-models)

Comment: On this moment, all the solutions i've found are to difficult for me. So I build one view which contained all the other views. But that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

There's lot of different ways to do this but I like events.

```
public class usercontrol1 :UserControl{
 public static EventHandler<sometype> NewType;
    public usercontrol1(){
           NewType +=(o,sometype)=>{
               //sometype has the content here.
           }
    }
}
```

//to use the code above from another control

```
 if(usercontrol1.NewType != null) usercontrol1.Newtype(someInstanceOfSomeType);
```

Some complain about close coupling, in that case you can create an extension method that does all the notifying instead.  Listeners simply wire up to the extension method.

This is a more "functional style" solution.

```
public static EventsXM{
    public static RegisterSomeTypeNotification(Action<sometype> Callback){
         userControl1.NewType +=(o,s)=>{
               Callback(s);
         }
    }
    public static NotifyNewData(this sometype data){
         if(usercontrol1.NewType!=null){
              usercontrol1.NetType(data)
         }
    }
}

//to use the XM
sometype.NotifyNewData();  //will send notification
RegisterSomeTypeNotification(data=>{
  //data has the value of sometype here... and is called only when new data arrives
});
```

While both should work some may complain about dangling event handlers... to fix that problem in the static methods there should be a way to deregister anyone listening for that event.

Answer (score 1):

To pass objects between your viewModels you can use a "messenger", it's based on C# events and it permits you to pass objects between classes. 
For example in MVVM light a messenger system is implemented, an permits you to send / receive objects in this way.

```
// Sends a message with a user object from ViewModel 1
User user = new user { Name = "testName" };
Messenger.Default.Send(user);

// Receive the user object in ViewModel 2
Messenger.Default.Register<User>(this, (user) =>
{
    // use "user" object
});
```

[Here](http://wbsimms.com/mvvm-light-toolkit-messaging-example/) is are some example using MVVM light.

Comment: Nice and simple...
Excellent!